# Filter options by value with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want filter with jquery the options by values,
If I have:

```
<select class="generic-widget" id="phone_line" name="phone_line">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2">71158189</option>
<option value="4">71158222</option>
<option value="3">99199152</option>
<option value="1">98199153</option>
</select>
```

For this case I must show the options with value="3" and value="4" only.

Using:

```
$('#phone_line option[value!="3"]').remove();
```

I only can filter by one value, but I need something to use with x values

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Kindly, explain your question briefly. I din't get you what are you trying to do....

Comment: The answer of Karl-André Gagnon is the good one: short and efficient!
You can test it with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a function like this:

```
function removeOptions(id,array){
    str='[value!=""]';
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        str += '[value!='+array[i]+']';
    }
    $('#'+id+' option'+ str ).remove();
}
```

If you have a array with the options that you don't want remove, like this:

```
var myopts = [3,4];
```

you only run:

```
removeOptions('phone_line', myopts);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to be re-using this over and over again, creating a function is a good idea. The below takes an array parameter of values you would like to remove:

```
function removeOptions(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $('#phone_line option[value="' + array[i] + '"]').remove();
    }
}
```

A quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/Ca2hb/1/

Answer (score 3):

Well first, i don't know where is `#line` but it is not in the HTML you provided us.

Second I would use :

```
$('#phone_line option[value!=3][value!=5]').remove();
```

It is possible to have 2 condition in one selector!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$("select[id*='line']").find('option[value!=3], option[value!=5]').remove();

or

$("select[id*='line']").children('option[value!=3], option[value!=5]').remove();
```

Thanks,

Comment: it select the element by checking the string "line" .similar to contains

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#phone_line option').filter(function(){
    return (this.value != 3 && this.value != 4);
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AgxB6/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only the options with values 3 and 4. It can be simply done via.

```
$('#phone_line option').not('option[value="3"],option[value="4"]').remove();
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut4bn/).

or You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for avoiding the option values with 4 and 3

```
$('#phone_line option').filter('option[value="3"],option[value="4"] ').remove();
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NhQqk/).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#line option[value!=3],option[value!=4]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#line').find('option[value!=3], option[value!=5]').remove();
```

If options are direct descendants use **.children()** instead of **.find()**